# называемых «нестероидные противовоспалительные препараты» - падеж?

Tags: управление

Подскажите, в каком падеже надо в этом случае писать фразу в кавычках?

1. Одним из вариантов лечения является прием обезболивающих средств, называемых «нестероидные противовоспалительные препараты».
2. Одним из вариантов лечения является прием обезболивающих средств, называемых «нестероидными противовоспалительными препаратами».

Я уверена, что правилен вариант 1, но не мог доказать этого, не могу найти правило.

Пожалуйста, скиньте ссылку на правило.

Спасибо

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Оба варианта допустимы, правила нет, поэтому и найти не можете. В научной литературе, чтобы проще было понять, чаще используется первый вариант. В обычном стиле - второй, причем кавычки часто опускают, особенно если предполагается, что сам термин читающему знаком.